# i want to add code through the form's input field(textarea) and then want to display it on the webpage

Tags: php, laravel

code is may be an iframe, script, video, div, etc.

here is the codewhich shows the code as text on the webpage.

```
@foreach($data['adds'] as $add)
```

```
<div class="col-md-4">
  <div class="box1">{{$add->code}}</div>
  <br>
  <!-- <div class="box2">awf</div> -->
</div>
```

@endforeach

i want when i add code through the form field then they show their actual result not just show same as text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To display unescaped data do like this,

```
@foreach($data['adds'] as $add)
<div class="col-md-4">
  <div class="box1">{!! $add->code !!}</div>
  <br>
</div>
@endforeach
```